# Partitioning BY HASH using VARCHAR field

Tags: mysql

In a given table, I am trying to apply a partitioning scheme where the field used is a VARCHAR (23), something like a Guid.

*Ex: 5cb4932bfbca0c0010343e68*

The idea is to create 4 partitions using hash partitioning. For this I believe that you have to use some function that converts the field into a value that always fits the partitioning clause, I don't know if this is possible in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  Id char(36) NOT NULL,
  ApiId varchar(23) NOT NULL,
  Classification int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
PARTITION BY HASH(ApiId)
PARTITIONS 4;
```

Comment: Does it work? Do you get an error? If so, what?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that information, it doesn't work, the error follows:

SQL Error [1659] [HY000]: Field 'ApiId' is of a not allowed type for this type of partitioning

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to supply a hash function which returns an integer. From [HASH partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-hash.html)...

> To partition a table using HASH partitioning, it is necessary to append to the CREATE TABLE statement a PARTITION BY HASH (expr) clause, where expr is an expression that returns an integer.

The simplest solution is to store your ID as an integer and convert it to a hex string as needed. This is faster than storing varchar and uses less memory.

Unfortunately your ID is also too large to fit into a bigint. It's about 92 bits. Instead, use `varbinary(12)` (and varbinary(16) for 128 bit UUIDs).

Then you need to write a hash function to turn that varbinary value into an integer for hashing. Unfortunately I don't know how to do that in MySQL.